# Print function log /stack trace for entire program using firebug

Tags: javascript, firebug

Firebug has the ability to log calls to a particular function name.  I'm looking for a bug that sometimes stops a page from rendering, but doesn't cause any errors or warnings.  The bug only appears about half the time.  So how do I get a list of all the function calls for the entire program, or some kind of stack trace for the execution of the entire program?

Answer (score 225, accepted):

[Firefox provides](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console#Stack_traces) **`console.trace()`**  which is very handy to print the call stack. It is also available in [Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console-api#consoletraceobject) and [IE 11](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn265073%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Alternatively try something like this:

```
function print_call_stack() {
  var stack = new Error().stack;
  console.log("PRINTING CALL STACK");
  console.log( stack );
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to increase the length of the stack? That would be very helpful.

Comment: ✚1 console.warn('[WARN] CALL STACK:', new Error().stack);

Answer (score 13):

When i need a stack trace i do the following, maybe you can draw some inspiration from it:

```
function logStackTrace(levels) {
    var callstack = [];
    var isCallstackPopulated = false;
    try {
        i.dont.exist += 0; //doesn't exist- that's the point
    } catch (e) {
        if (e.stack) { //Firefox / chrome
            var lines = e.stack.split('\n');
            for (var i = 0, len = lines.length; i < len; i++) {
                    callstack.push(lines[i]);
            }
            //Remove call to logStackTrace()
            callstack.shift();
            isCallstackPopulated = true;
        }
        else if (window.opera && e.message) { //Opera
            var lines = e.message.split('\n');
            for (var i = 0, len = lines.length; i < len; i++) {
                if (lines[i].match(/^\s*[A-Za-z0-9\-_\$]+\(/)) {
                    var entry = lines[i];
                    //Append next line also since it has the file info
                    if (lines[i + 1]) {
                        entry += " at " + lines[i + 1];
                        i++;
                    }
                    callstack.push(entry);
                }
            }
            //Remove call to logStackTrace()
            callstack.shift();
            isCallstackPopulated = true;
        }
    }
    if (!isCallstackPopulated) { //IE and Safari
        var currentFunction = arguments.callee.caller;
        while (currentFunction) {
            var fn = currentFunction.toString();
            var fname = fn.substring(fn.indexOf("function") + 8, fn.indexOf("(")) || "anonymous";
            callstack.push(fname);
            currentFunction = currentFunction.caller;
        }
    }
    if (levels) {
        console.log(callstack.slice(0, levels).join('\n'));
    }
    else {
        console.log(callstack.join('\n'));
    }
};
```

**Moderator's note**: The code in this answer seems to also appear in [this post from Eric Wenderlin's blog](http://www.eriwen.com/javascript/js-stack-trace/). The author of this answer claims it as his own code, though, written prior to the blog post linked here. Just for purposes of good-faith, I've added the link to the post and this note.

Comment: There is a console.trace() call you can make in Firebug that does this.

Comment: This is brilliant. Firebug has troubles with minified files, this script does it!

Comment: FWIW @andrew-barber, author of the answer never claimed as his own. Just didn't attribute. Your edit should be a comment.

Answer (score 8):

I accomplished this without firebug.  Tested in both chrome and firefox:

```
console.error("I'm debugging this code.");
```

Once your program prints that to the console, you can click the little arrow to it to expand the call stack.

Answer (score 2):

Try stepping through your code one line or one function at a time to determine where it stops working correctly. Or make some reasonable guesses and scatter logging statements through your code.

Comment: This. Definitely add a load of `console.log('something')` statements to your functions to see which ones are (and aren't) being called

Comment: The program is huge, so I am looking for a way to compare function logs for when the program ran correctly vs when it did not.

Comment: I concur that this would be useful. I am stepping in to take ownership of a large code base and something that can generate a running trace of all function calls would certainly help get a sense of the flow/shape of the code and detect dead code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
console.trace()
```

I don't know if it's supported on all browsers, so I would check if it exists first.