# Firebug: console.trace gives no output

Tags: javascript, firefox, firebug, stack-trace

I can't make Firebug's `console.trace()` give any output. Am I using it wrongly?
I'm using Firefox 41.0.1 and Firebug 2.0.12 on Ubuntu 14.04. It works fine in Firefox 41.0.1 on Windows 7.

I've uploaded [a test file](http://definemyhouse.neocities.org/index.html) to neocities so you can try it out. This is the content of the test file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function myFun1 (p1) {
            var res = myFun2("there");
            return res;
        }

        function myFun2 (p2) {
            console.trace();
            return "hi there"
        }

        console.log("start");
        var res = myFun1("hi");
        console.log("res: ", res);
        console.log("end");

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: same on gentoo with FF 41.0.1 and FB 2.0.12, and no you dont use it wrongly.

Comment: Seems to be a bug, I used the following workaround:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4671031/print-function-log-stack-trace-for-entire-program-using-firebug

Comment: Indeed reported as Bug: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/firebug/T47kEK8gtKU/AUP4behABAAJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to a [thread in the Firebug discussion group](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/firebug/T47kEK8gtKU/discussion) this is a bug in Firebug 2.0.12, which was reported as [issue #7948](https://github.com/firebug/firebug/issues/7948) and be fixed in Firebug 2.0.13.