# How does recursion works behind the scenes of the Call Stack?

Tags: recursion

I understand the logic of recursion a function calls a function with base case then terminate, what I have here is a code which logs a simple recursion, what I don't get is it started logging with the condition reached, condition met: 0?

```js
function factorialize(num) {

    if(num === 0){
        console.log('condition met: '+num);
        return 1;
    }

    var x = factorialize(num-1); // iterate
    var toReturn = num*x;

    console.log("Current call: num = " + num
            + " x = " + x
            + "\n"
            + "Returning " + toReturn
            );

    return toReturn;

}

factorialize(5);
```

I was expecting this code to log the output first and lastly the condition is reached?

output and [demo](https://repl.it/Cmxn/1)
[image: output]

Comment: *to understand recursion, you need to first understand recursion* **chuckles**

Comment: why did it log the base case first? @vaxquis

Comment: because `factorialize(5)` calls `factorialize(4)`, which calls `factorialize(3)`, which calls `factorialize(2)`, which calls `factorialize(1)`, which calls `factorialize(0)`?

Comment: You should be able to "execute" this code on paper to understand how it works. Execution hits that `console.log` first.

Comment: @vaxquis got it, is there a way that I can see the call stack on debugger or how can I log them?

Comment: @learningjavascriptks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280389/how-do-you-find-out-the-caller-function-in-javascript http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4671031/print-function-log-stack-trace-for-entire-program-using-firebug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [already pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38946788/how-does-recursion-works-behind-the-scenes-of-the-call-stack?noredirect=1#comment65248687_38946788), it's

because factorialize(5) calls factorialize(4), which calls factorialize(3), which calls factorialize(2), which calls factorialize(1), which calls factorialize(0)

And then all the logs occurs.

Comment: can you please elaborate more about the call stack? I was confused with my output, at the very bottom, it logs returning 120. so it returned 120, but why is the condition met at the very first line on the log?

Comment: When the code starts it enters the function the first time. Check your if which returns false and pauses execution of the function to enter it second time... And so on, until the last call prints your "condition met" and it ends the function and continues from the last function call to finish it too, so it prints the next log, and again continue the last function call and prints again until execution terminates

Comment: @vaxquis thanks for the edit

Comment: @Yitschak n/p, mate.

Answer (score 1):

In recursion, first you go "in", then you come "out".

Anything before the recursive `factorialize` call is on the way "in".

Anything after it is on the way "out".

Since your second `console.log` statement comes after the recursive call, it executes on the way "out".

Your first `console.log` statement is inside an `if` statement.
The `if` statement comes before the recursive call, so it is tested at every level on the way "in", but it only does the `console.log` statement when it arrives at the *bottom* of the well.